# Is there a way to passing a list of boolean values to a parent element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i'm not sure if I can do something like this...

In first place I've a component which render two tables

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TableList from './TableOne';

class ComponentWhichRendersTwoTables extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <TableList
                    rows={ rows }
                />
                <TableList
                    rows={ rows }
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}

const rows = [
    { id: 1, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 2, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 3, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 4, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 5, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 6, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 7, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 8, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
    { id: 9, fieldOne: 'fieldOne', fieldTwo: 'fieldTwo' },
];

export default ComponentWhichRendersTwoTables;
```

Then, in the table i've a TableRow rendering rows times

```
import React from 'react';
import TableRow from './TableRow';

function TableList({ rows }) {
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th/>
                <th>Title One</th>
                <th>Title Two</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                { rows.map(row => (
                    <TableRow
                      row={ row }
                    />
                )) }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

export default TableList;
```

And then the TableRow component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TableRow({ row }) {
    const [icon, useIcon] = useState(false);

    clickHandler = () => {
        useIcon(!icon)
    }

    const { fieldOne, fieldTwo } = row;
    const isActive = icon ? '-active' : ''
    return (
        <tr>
            <td onClick={clickHandler} className={`fancyIcon${isActive} `}>
                ICON
            </td>
            <td>{fieldOne}</td>
            <td>{fieldTwo}</td>
        </tr>
    );
}

export default TableRow;
```

The thing here is that i would like to end up with the next output functionallity:

In the component rendering two tables, the first one is a list of fields that I get from an API 
and the other is a list that will be filled as the user clicks the elements of the first one.

So let's suppose that in the original one i've four row elements and the user clicks the first two. In this case the second table should display this two elements that the user has clicked.

I would like to know if there's a way to do it without refs.

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than posting an answer on your question, it's better to edit your original post to include the missing context. Can you edit your post and integrate the information you posted as an answer in and delete your answer post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused as to what values you're wanting to pass from child to parent, but the answer doesn't really change. In order to accomplish this, you need to pass an update function to the child and call it there. Something like this could work:

```
const parent = () => {
 const [values, setValues] = useState({...objWithSomeValues})

 return (
   <Child setValues={setValues} values={values}/>
  )

};

const Child = (props) => {
  const {setValues} = props;
  return (
    <button onClick={()=> {setValues({...values, update: updateValue })}}>Click Me!</button>
  )
};
```

This is an overly simplistic version of this that doesn't account for re-renders and other things that might complicate your particular set up. The update function also doesn't have to be a setState hook. It could be your own custom function.